# How to create XML file and write data into it using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to create a XMl and write data into it using JavaScript. I have tried using XMLHttpRequest and ActiveXObject. But of them are not working. Please help me out.

Comment: You need server-side code.

Answer (score 0):

You can create `XmlDocument` objects : http://help.dottoro.com/ljbcjfot.php then send it via `XMLHttpRequest` to a server page that will save it to a filé